# The knife tool does not snap to a line

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices

The knife tool refuses to snap to a line I created between two vertices to create a quad.

[image]

I am on the 3.5.1 version of Blender, and I'm following the [Get Good at Blender - Advanced Topology - The Knight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_8zhJm9EbU) tutorial.

Here is the blend file.
[image]

Comment: My guess is that you joined the two vertices with an edge but it didn't actually cut the face. Go into Face mode (3 on the keyboard) and see if clicking the face that you created is giving the result you expect. If we can see your Blend file we'd be able to confirm that so please share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/ pasting the link on that page into your question..

Comment: I just checked with the Face select mode, and the entire thing is one entire face. I'll try sharing the blend file

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here you go. I have deleted that big face because it was separated from the edges. And created every face from the edges by pressing <kbd>F</kbd>.
Now you can cut it. And you should add the Mirror modifier again, because I removed it too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll be more mindful of faces and edges now.

Comment: For future reference I suspect you must have used the 'F' key to join the vertices rather than 'J'.  In that particular case 'F' will just fill the gap between two verts with an edge without actually cutting the face. That is why the large face still remained and why I suggested selecting it to see what was going on. You could have just deleted all the loose edges by selecting them and then deleting with X, then tried again using J rather than deleting the face but @Likar got there first! :^)

Comment: I don't think this is a very good answer by Stack Exchange standards. It would be way better if it attempted to give an actual answer instead of(or in addition to) corrected file. It provides no explanation about why or what is happening.